# Redux - external libs and "React" in reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-intl

I have simple Redux reducer, but for some actions I need to show notifications, in order to do so I need to trigger my custom notification function within the reducer so:

```
case REDUCER_ACTION_NAME:
  notificationDisplay.success("Message", {
    additionalStuff: extraOptions
});
```

What's even worse I'm using `react-intl` for translations and I need the `"Message"`o be translate-ready so I'm adding this to the mix:

```
case REDUCER_ACTION_NAME:
  notificationDisplay.success(<FormattedMessage id="message" defaultMessage="Message" />, {
    additionalStuff: extraOptions
});
```

It creates a translation in span and requires `react` so my reducer starts with these imports:

```
import React from 'react';
import notificationDisplay from 'my-notifications';
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';

import {
  // all the actions
} from './actions.jsx';

// reducer
```

Is it okay? I feel something here is off - like importing `React` in reducers is an anti-pattern, because all reducer examples I could find are so clean and sleek and there are no external libs there whatsoever.

Am I right or am I wrong and my code is perfectly fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not do any kind of computations in reducer. It should change the state and nothing else. The way you are using it is a complete anti-pattern. Because it is doing some UI actions. And Redux is nothing to do with the UI. It should be used as the store and only the store.

But you can use **Actions** which is way better than doing it in reducer.

Best way to achieve your goal is to use your reducer to just push the messages into an array in the redux store. And create a Container that uses that messages array to show success or error messages. And create a timer that removes the message from the array after some time.

Just look at the https://github.com/diegoddox/react-redux-toastr repo they are doing it very well.

Thanks

Akhil P